# RDLC Report Service giving error when sum column

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, reporting, rdlc

I'm using a Access Database to pull Data and displaying using Report

In my table theirs a Column holding Commission data however every time I add

`=Sum(Fields!Commission.Value)` in a empty Cell to display the Sum value I get a Error.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
=Sum(int(Fields!Commission.Value))
```

may be you are using `string` so first convert it into `int`

Answer (score 1):

[Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159134%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) in `SSRS` requires two fields to sum up and there must be an `=` sign before your function..like this

```
=Sum(Fields!Commission.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maker sure the field is Int and not String if so convert it to integer to sum.

Comment: I have the same problem how can i convert my string to int ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514140/error-in-expression-in-rdlc-sum-command

Comment: @EhsanAkbar i only you would have tagged me i would have answered instantly.